# What does "graphql.NewList(type)" do?

Tags: go, graphql, graphql-go

As it turns out, [graphql-go](https://godoc.org/github.com/graphql-go/graphql)'s help doc is not beginner friendly. I'm simply wondering what .NewList() does in, say, the following code: `Type: graphql.NewList(types.Workouts)`

Answer (score 1):

It means `array` type

> Lists work in a similar way: We can use a type modifier to mark a type
>   as a List, which indicates that this field will return an `array` of
>   that type. In the schema language, this is denoted by wrapping the
>   type in square brackets, `[` and `]`.

```
// js
languages: {
    type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLList(GraphQLString))
}

// schema language
languages: [String]! // returns empty array or array of strings
```

[docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqllist)